# Insert and update records in one TSQL statement?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table BigTable and a table LittleTable. I want to move **a copy** of some records from BigTable into LittleTable and then (for these records) set BigTable.ExportedFlag to T (indicating that a copy of the record has been moved to little table).

Is there any way to do this in one statement?

I know I can do a transaction to:

1. moves the records from big table based on a where clause
2. updates big table setting exported to T based on this same where clause.

I've also looked into a [MERGE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which does not seem quite right, because I don't want to change values in little table, just move records to little table.

I've looked into an [OUTPUT clause](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/) after the update statement but can't find a useful example. I don't understand why Pinal Dave is using `Inserted.ID, Inserted.TEXTVal, Deleted.ID, Deleted.TEXTVal` instead of `Updated.TextVal`. Is the update considered an insertion or deletion?

I found this post [TSQL: UPDATE with INSERT INTO SELECT FROM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742540/tsql-update-with-insert-into-select-from) saying "AFAIK, you cannot update two different tables with a single sql statement."

Is there a clean single statement to do this? I am looking for a correct, maintainable SQL statement. Do I have to wrap two statements in a single transaction?

Comment: "Is the update considered an insertion or deletion" - an `UPDATE` can be modelled as a `DELETE` and an `INSERT` - In fact, internally, SQL Server *sometimes* performs such a transformation - so anything dealing with the *result* of an update (e.g. `OUTPUT`, `MERGE` or an `UPDATE` trigger) has it modelled as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `OUTPUT` clause as long as `LittleTable` meets the requirements to be the target of an `OUTPUT ... INTO`

```
UPDATE BigTable
SET ExportedFlag = 'T'
OUTPUT inserted.Col1, inserted.Col2 INTO LittleTable(Col1,Col2)
WHERE <some_criteria>
```

It makes no difference if you use `INSERTED` or `DELETED`. The only column it will be different for is the one you are updating (`deleted.ExportedFlag` has the before value and `inserted.ExportedFlag` will be `T`)